# php function causes page to hang

Tags: php, laravel, memory, foreach

I'm currently tearing my hair out trying to get this function to work on my test server.

This looks in a very large directory of files (about 4000 files in nested folders) and creates a file tree.

I've tested this script and similar ones on my local machine and it works fine, but I'm finding that on a live server if I uncomment the commented out line it will cause the page to hang indefinitely. No errors are output and I can't seem to find any logs. I've maxed out my php memory on the server and upped the max input vars and process time etc etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function read_dir_content($parent_dir, $depth = 0, $rememberFiles = [], $tree = [], $first = 'first', $rand = 0){
    $str_result = "<ul class=\"files {$first}\" id=\"collapse{$rand}\">";
    if ($handle = opendir($parent_dir)) 
    {
        $array = [];

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if(in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) continue; // ignore . and ..
            if(substr($file, 0, 1) == '.') continue; // ignore invisible files
            $array[] = $parent_dir . '/' . $file;

        }
        closedir($handle);

        if (count($array)) {
            // order the array here...
            foreach($array as $path) {
                $relPath = str_replace(Dataroom::basePath() . '/', '', $path);
                $name = basename($path);
                $checked = false;
                if( is_dir($path) ){ // folders
                    $encoded = base64_encode($relPath . '/');
                    $newrand = mt_rand($rand+1, $rand+1000000); // set random number
                    $state = in_array(md5($encoded), $tree) ? 'true' : 'false';
                    $state2 = $state == 'true' ? 'collapse in' : 'collapse';
                    $folderIcon = $state == 'true' ? 'glyphicon-folder-open' : 'glyphicon-folder-close';
                    $checked = old('folders.'.$encoded) || in_array($encoded, $rememberFiles) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    $str_result .= "<li class=\"folder text-primary\">";
                        $str_result .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" {$checked} id=\"{$encoded}\" name=\"files[{$encoded}]\">&nbsp;"; // folder checkboxes will be ignored without a name attribute
                        $str_result .= "<span class=\"glyphicon {$folderIcon}\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>&nbsp;";
                        $str_result .= '<a class="collapse'.$newrand.'" onclick="rememberTreeState(\''.$encoded.'\');" aria-expanded="'.$state.'" aria-controls="collapse'.$newrand.'" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse'.$newrand.'">'.$name.'<span class="caret"></span></a>'; // link

                        //$str_result .= '<a href="http://test"></a>'; // THIS LINE CAUSES PAGE TO HANG!!!

                        $str_result .= read_dir_content($path, $depth++, $rememberFiles, $tree, $state2, $newrand);
                    $str_result .= "</li>";


                } else { // files
                    $encoded = base64_encode($relPath);
                    if (!empty(old() && old('files'))) {
                        if (old('files.'.$encoded)) {
                            $checked = 'checked="checked"'; // remember input from last errored form submission
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (in_array($encoded, $rememberFiles)) {
                            $checked = 'checked="checked"'; // remember files from group db records
                        }
                    }

                    $str_result .= "<li class=\"file text-muted\"><input type=\"checkbox\" {$checked} name=\"files[{$encoded}]\">&nbsp;<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-file\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>&nbsp;{$name}</li>";

                }
            }
            unset($path);
            unset($handle);
        }
    }
    $str_result .= "</ul>";

    return $str_result;
}
```

It seems like it's just reaching some kind of memory limit and everything stops but my server knowledge isn't that great so I'm really stuck. I'm sure the syntax is OK so it must be something else.

Comment: Is there a difference between PHP version on your local and live?

Comment: Yes, local is 5.5.10, live is 5.6.17

Comment: I've noticed if I swap the base64_encode for md5 it works but I need a reversible encrytion for my url (doesn't need to be secure).

Comment: So it looks like it's the base64_encoding that's causing the issue. Whether it's because of some illegal characters or because of string length or memory I'm not sure.

Any suggestions on a short url safe reversible encryption for urls? Doesn't need to be secure.

Comment: This seems to be related to the length of the string I'm trying to output so I've opened another question

Answer (score 0):

This looks to some kind of php/apache buffering issue.

I've not managed to find out the definitive answer for this yet, but a workaround is to calculate the page content size and add it to the header info.